# Which enzymes degrade dynorphins and what drugs inhibit these enzymes?

Tags: pharmacology, enzymes, opioid, dynorphin

Which enzymes degrade dynorphins and what drugs are there available to inhibit said enzymes?

Answer (score 1):

[This paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8957219) was looking at inhibition of dynorphin converting enzymes and their importance. Although they don't seem to know if it is a single enzyme, or if it is multiple enzymes.

[This paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17087727) looked at bikunin as an endogenous inhibitor of dynorphin convertase in human cerebrospinal fluid.

[This paper](http://informahealthcare.com/doi/abs/10.3109/14756369109030394) looked at several inhibitors (some of which are known to irreversibly inhibit other enzymes), like *N*-peptidyl-*O*-acyl hydroxylamines and their effects on hCSF-DCE, the enzyme that cleaves dynorphin A, dynorphin B and alpha-neoendorphin to release Leu-enkephalin-Arg<sup>6</sup>. However, it is known to inhibit serine and cysteine proteinases.

However, I don't see any actual medications that are meant to inhibit Dynorphin enzymes. Instead I found [Al-Fayoumi et. al](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15359581) were actually looking to identify stabilized dynorphin A derivatives instead of just inhibition of enzymes.

Comment: Although nicely referenced, a list of articles touching on OP's question is not a suitable answer. The answer should be *supported* by references, a reference list in itself is not an answer.

Comment: I did say at the end of my answer that I hadn't come across any medications that specifically inhibited Dynorphin enzymes @AliceD and pulled from those articles what they had used to inhibit the enzymes. I also noted that hCSF-DCE is the enzyme responsible for cleaving dynorphins.

Comment: Yes I agree that your answer is quite complete and I removed my downvote. I do still believe it is not a well-formulated answer, so I will not upvote.